# plovr warning on new closure <constructor>.base()

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, plovr

I checked out the latest plovr and added closure to my project using bower. while compiling the code with closure-compiler.jar in advanced_compilation works without any error or warning, using plovr gives the following errors:

```
/closure/goog/ui/buttonrenderer.js:107: WARNING - goog.ui.ButtonRenderer.base is never defined
var element = goog.ui.ButtonRenderer.base(this, 'createDom', button);
^
/closure/goog/ui/menu.js:425: WARNING - goog.ui.Menu.base is never defined
var handled = goog.ui.Menu.base(this, 'handleKeyEventInternal', e);
^
/closure/goog/ui/menu.js:447: WARNING - goog.ui.Menu.base is never defined
goog.ui.Menu.base(this, 'setHighlightedIndex', index);
^
/closure/goog/ui/select.js:61: WARNING - goog.ui.Select.base is never defined
goog.ui.Select.base(this, 'constructor',
^
/closure/goog/ui/select.js:142: WARNING - goog.ui.Select.base is never defined
goog.ui.Select.base(this, 'handleMenuAction', e);
^
```

I have set closure library in config.js using

```
"closure-library": "bower_components/closure-library/closure/goog/",
```

is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mismatch that is bound to happen when an updated Library is used along with a stale Compiler release (Plovr is known to get behind compiler releases). These particular warnings are about `.base` not being supported by the Compiler release bundled with Plovr. `.base` was introduced as an alternative to `goog.base` and the `superClass_` property to comply with ES5 strict when expressing inheritance (no poking `arguments.callee`).

Here are a few options:

- Use the closure-library bundled with Plovr
- Grab [Plovr's source](https://github.com/bolinfest/plovr/); replace closure-compiler and build with `ant build` (I have personally not tried this recently)
- The [Medium](http://medium.com) team maintain their own [Plovr fork](https://github.com/Medium/plovr), which is more in line with recent Closure Compiler releases. Since you're in a node environment, you can try with [NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/plovr): `npm install plovr --save-dev` (I use this fork personally with an updated vanilla Library checkout)